# Cannot target <form> element using `getByRole`

Tags: playwright

I am having a strange situation since yesterday in my SvelteKit project. I cannot manage to target a simple `<form>` element with `getByRole`, although it works well with `locator`.
I don't know if there's something I do bad, or if there's a limitation or issue in Playwright.

I have the following component:

```html
<form name="login" method="POST">
    <label class="label">
        <span>Username</span>
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="SautMoine" />
    </label>

    <button>Login</button>
</form>
```

Here is the output HTML (copied from "Show page source" when debugging the Playwright test and adding a breakpoint):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="dark">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        
        <link href="./_app/immutable/assets/0.e14bb904.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover" data-theme="skeleton">
        <div style="display: contents">  <form name="login" method="POST" data-svelte-h="svelte-7wo5te"><label class="label"><span>Username</span> <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="SautMoine"></label> <button>Login</button></form> 
            
            <script>
                {
                    __sveltekit_4e87w5 = {
                        base: new URL(".", location).pathname.slice(0, -1),
                        env: {}
                    };

                    const element = document.currentScript.parentElement;

                    const data = [null,null];

                    Promise.all([
                        import("./_app/immutable/entry/start.9963b95b.js"),
                        import("./_app/immutable/entry/app.0a54c320.js")
                    ]).then(([kit, app]) => {
                        kit.start(app, element, {
                            node_ids: [0, 2],
                            data,
                            form: null,
                            error: null
                        });
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And now here is the test that I perform:

```js
import { expect, test } from '@playwright/test'
test('display a form', async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto('/')
    // The following `expect` passes
    await expect(page.locator('form')).toHaveAttribute('method', 'POST')
    // The following `expect` fails
    await expect(page.getByRole('form')).toHaveAttribute('method', 'POST')
})
```

My problem is that the first `expect` passes (which is normal) but not the second one (using the `getByRole`):

```
Error: Timed out 5000ms waiting for expect(received).toHaveAttribute(expected)


Expected string: "POST"
Received string: ""
Call log:
  - expect.toHaveAttribute with timeout 5000ms
  - waiting for getByRole('form')

    at e2e\test.e2e.ts:13:39
```

I would like to be able to use the `getByRole`, rather than `locator`. Does anyone have a clue what's happening here?

I created this form using Vitest and Testing Library and everything was fine, but I was investigating using Playwright to test my component, hence the move to the Playwright test from an existing form. To be complete, I was first using the (experimental) component testing of Playwright and I end up with "normal" page testing because I thought my problem was coming from the component testing part of Playwright, but it seems it's not. In case it's needed, here is the component test in Playwright:

```js
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/experimental-ct-svelte'
import Page from './+page.svelte'
test('display a form', async ({ mount }) => {
    const component = await mount(Page)
    // The following `expect` passes
    await expect(component.locator('form')).toHaveAttribute('method', 'POST')
    // The following `expect` fails
    await expect(component.getByRole('form')).toHaveAttribute('method', 'POST')
})
```

which fails in the same way:

```
Error: Timed out 5000ms waiting for expect(received).toHaveAttribute(expected)


Expected string: "POST"
Received string: ""
Call log:
  - expect.toHaveAttribute with timeout 5000ms
  - waiting for locator('#root').locator('internal:control=component').getByRole('form')

    at src\routes\page.ui-spec.ts:16:44
```

I searched in the documentation if anything was related to this or form handling, I watched videos and followed guides on how to implement component testing, I tried adding other attributes (such as `id`, `action`), I tried targeting other attributes, I tried targeting other elements (which is working fine), I displayed the HTML and took screenshots to make sure my form was really there and I changed lots of many things here and there that I cannot remember, in the process of trying to understand why this happened.

Comment: A form _element_ only has the form _role_ if it has an accessible name.

Comment: Yes, but I added a `name="login"` attribute in my form. Was it not enough?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Indeed, it was not enough! I read [this documentation on providing accessible names](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/names-and-descriptions/) and it is recommended to use `aria-label` for `form`s. And guess what? When I add this attribute everything works well!!! Many thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe comment, I finally understood that the problem was that the `form` role was not given to my form because it did not have an accessible name. I thought that this part was OK because I provided a `name` attribute, but it appears that (according to [this documentation on providing accessible names](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/names-and-descriptions/)) an accessible name for a `form` should be provided using `aria-label`, and not `name`.
And when I add this attribute to my form, the Playwright test is passing as expected!

Many thanks again to @jonrsharpe!